# How can I connect 3 harmonic oscillators in series?

Tags: python

I have a code for a simple harmonic oscillator from this article https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/understanding-oscillators-python-2813ec38781d

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
t = np.linspace(0,15,1000)
omega_sq = 1
y = [0,2] #y[0]=x and y[1]=v
def harmonic(t,y):
    solution = [y[1],-omega_sq*y[0]]
    return solution
sho = solve_ivp(harmonic, [0,1000], y0 = y, t_eval = t)
plt.plot(t,sho.y[0])
plt.ylabel("Position")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.title('SHO', fontsize = 20)
```

How can I connect this in series? That means I have to give this output as input to the next oscillator, which is the same.

Comment: The question would be easier to answer if the code had comments briefly explaining what each line (or bunch of lines) of code does.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service.  When you say connect the oscillator in series, what do you mean programmatically?  Do you want to take the output of one pass and feed it to a second pass?, etc?  If, yes what would a for loop look like?

Comment: That is what my question was, I know its not a tutoring service don't try to be authoritative with the new comers , that's not good way to answer to new comers ,  I know we have a coupled oscillator methods and some other methods, I want to know what are other ways to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If by oscillator connected in series you mean coupled oscillators, then it is simple, it is just about writing your system in a matrix form.

Let's say you are about to model a system like:

```
|    k1             K            k2    |
|-/\/\/\/\-(m1)-/\/\/\/\-(m2)-/\/\/\/\-|
|                                      |
```

With two masses `m1`, `m2` and three springs of strength `k1`, `k2` and `K`.

```
M @ x''(t) + K @ x(t) = 0
```

First, import required libraries:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then describe your setup in its matrix form:

```
m1 = 5
m2 = 1

k1 = 1
k2 = 5
K = 10

M = np.array([
    [m1, 0],
    [0, m2]
])

K = np.array([
    [k1 + K, -K],
    [-K, k2 + K]
])

Minv = np.linalg.inv(M)

W = Minv @ K
```

Now reduce the linear second order ODE system into the equivalent system of first order equations as you did for the one dimensional case:

```
def system(t, y, w):
    n = w.shape[0]
    return np.hstack([y[n:2*n], -w @ y[0:n]])
```

Chose the initial conditions for the IVP and integrate as usual:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 20, 10000)
solution = integrate.solve_ivp(system, [t.min(), t.max()], y0=[0, 0, -1, 1], args=(W,), t_eval=t)
```

Confirm the solver succeed:

```
  message: 'The solver successfully reached the end of the integration interval.'
     nfev: 590
     njev: 0
      nlu: 0
      sol: None
   status: 0
  success: True
```

Finally render the solution to check out the behaviour of your system:

[image]
[image]
[image]